# JS getter not returning dynamic result

Tags: javascript, getter

I am making a simple game, it's divided into game generators, which generate values, and game engine, that interacts with user.

```
class Generator {
  constructor() {
    this.intro = 'Answer "yes" if number even otherwise answer "no"!';
    this.question = null;
    this.answer = null;
  }
  get game() {
    this.question = getRandomInt(10);
    this.answer = this.question % 2 === 0 ? 'yes' : 'no';
    return [this.question, this.answer];
  }
}

const newGame = new Generator();

const gameEven = () => game(newGame.intro, newGame.game);
```

However, when I launch game, I found that it cycles through the same number. I used `get game()` specifically because MDN states that is allows to return a [dynamically computed value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), why it didn't work?

Comment: Can you post the code for the `getRandomInt()` function please?

Comment: `const getRandomInt = max => Math.floor(Math.random() * (Math.floor(max) - 1)) + 1;`

Comment: What does the `game(newGame.intro, newGame.game)` function do?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what problem you having, but I don't think it's `JS getter not returning dynamic result`

Below is a simple Snippet that demonstrates the dynamic nature of a getter..

As you can see you get 2 different random numbers when you call `game`

```js
class Generator {
  get game() {
    return Math.random();
  }
}

var v = new Generator();
console.log(v.game);
console.log(v.game);
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that in both of the `console.log` the same instance of `v.game` is called?

Comment: Yes, there is only one instance.  As I've only called new once.